# Current sensing in H bridge for Stall detection-Purpose of Diode

Tags: diodes, current-measurement

I have a circuit, which is powered from two 1.5 V AA battery. It has a MCU and PNP - NPN Hbridge for driving motor. The motor (RF-300CA-11400) datasheet is here in this [Link][1]. The Motor will be turned in one direction for around 2 seconds or stall happens, whichever is earlier. and will be turned in opposite direction for 1-2 seconds appropriately. No sudden (few ms) change in the direction of motor expected.

My objective is to detect whether the motor is running and to also stop the motor as soon as the motor stalls.
Stalling current is 170 mA.
Typical load current is 70 mA.
Battery voltage: 2.2 to 3 V.

The present circuit is as follows:

**Question**: For high side current sensing, even without diode, i would see a drop and recognize that as stall current or load current appropriately. What might be the value addition/intelligence of the diode which is in between the battery and the H bridge?

PS: I am not sure about diode part number and i am unable to share the design reference
Thank you for your time

Comment: I have reread your question several times, and I do not understand what you are asking. Specifically, I do not understand what you are proposing to do with the diode.

Comment: The circuit is not designed by me. i am just trying to understand and appreciate the design. Hope this helps. Is the diode a part of Motor current safety feature or for current sensing? I am trying to understand role of the diode D1 in the above circuit. Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the original design?

Comment: Hi Sean, sorry to say that i cannot quote the reference as it is internal. But i just rechecked the connection and is the same way as presented above.

Comment: Well, then I can only offer a guess. The diodes only function appears to guarantee that there will be some known voltage differential between the "MCU and Motor Supply" connection and the "MCU ADC" connection. This may be necessary for the safety of the ADC.

Comment: I see. But, when the motor is not running, MCU_ADC will see 3V itself. isn't it?

Comment: Almost. But pn junctions all have a built in potential caused by the depletion region. It is this potential you have to overcome to cause conduction. This design guarantees it not to be identical - especially with that capacitor there.

Comment: If i assume the DC motor is running continuously in one direction, then, the motor current will be around 70 mA which is like a resistor of 42 ohms approx. Then, the voltage at the cathode of D1(<200 mV) will be still less than the junction potential (~0.5 V). SO,odes the diode conduct during normal operation (Except stalling)

Comment: There is some ambiguity. Even at stall current, even if it all went through the resistor alone, the potential across the resistor would only be .374 volts. I cannot say the diode will continue conducting in steady state or at stall because I don't think it will. The only remaining conclusion I can come up with is that the diode ensures a potential difference between the two nodes at all times.

Comment: Wont the voltage at the MCU_ADC node will be 3 V when the motor is not running?

Comment: No. At stop, the voltage divider of the 2.2 ohm resistor and the 1 Megohm resistor has a similar effect. The diode should still remain unbiased.

Comment: Would this design work with a stepper motor? Or is it for a DC motor?
For a stepper would a stall lead to current increase?

Comment: @Selim The Motor type is Brushed DC Motor. Design is intended for the same only. Datasheet link is in the message above. I do not have more experience on stepper motor drive

Comment: @Selim, I have corrected a mistake at MCU ADC Pin. Does it make any sense now?

Comment: @Selim I measured the forward voltage of the diode and it was 0.17 V. Does this give any hints?